# Meaning of "捻り" in context of swearing

Tags: meaning

Context is that protagonist is swearing. And says following sentence:

> 捻りもクソもねえな。

I know クソ, but I'm not sure what 捻り means here. Is this some slang or just some obvious (for Japanese) usage of literal meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「捻{ひね}り（が/の）ない」

is a common expression meaning:

> "boring", "plain", "witless", "uninteresting", etc.

(「捻り」 means "a twist" all by itself.  The expression is not really slang though it is colloquial.)

By inserting a 「もクソも」, the expression sounds more emphatic in a vulgar and lively way.

> "It's boring as hell!"